# How to get all users that belong in an AppRole using Azure Active Directory Graph API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I can't for the life of me figure out how to query Azure Active Directory's Graph API to get all users that belong to a particular AppRole.

First I tried something like:

```
client.Users.Where(u => u.AppRoleAssignments.Any(r => r.Id == "some-guid"));
```

But that won't compile because AppRoleAssignments is a IPagedCollection so you can't do things like .Any on it.

Then I tried to query all the AppRoleAssignments in the ServicePrincipal for my Application:

```
var servicePrincipal = await client.ServicePrincipals
    .Expand(p => p.AppRoleAssignments)
    .Where(p => p.AppId == "my app id guid")
    .ExecuteSingleAsync();
```

But `servicePrincipal.AppRoleAssignments` stubbornly comes back empty seemingly ignoring my .Expand.

I also tried getting the ServicePrincipal directly by ID and doing an Expand:

```
var principal = await client.ServicePrincipals
    .GetByObjectId("feeaae9c-40a3-48a3-8a01-b87343f5ecfc")
    .Expand(p => p.AppRoleAssignments)
    .ExecuteAsync();
```

But that just causes an error (which goes away if you remove the .Expand):

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Invalid object identifier 'feeaae9c-40a3-48a3-8a01-b87343f5ecfc()'."}}}
```

Which is an odd error because the object id in the error message is suffixed with a '()' that is not added by my code.

Am I missing something obvious? Surely there's an easy way to get all users in an AppRole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer. In order get to AppRoleAssignments off the ServicePrincipal you need to query the list directly rather than trying to expand it off the ServicePrincipal:

```
await client.ServicePrincipals
    .GetByObjectId(servicePrincipalObjectId)
    .AppRoleAssignedTo
    .ExecuteAsync()
```

Then you have to manually walk through the users and groups to get a final list of users. This could potentially result in many Graph API service calls depending on how many groups and users there are, so be warned!

**Edit:** As Dan Kershaw mentions in the comments, roles are only applied to users in groups that are directly linked to AppRoles. Sub-groups do not inherit the roles.

I've put up the full solution in a Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/daniel-chambers/5e3702d40cd16c767ed1) because it's really too big to put inline here.

Comment: Thanks for posting this Daniel.  I'll chat to our engineering team about any improvements we can make in this space.  One thing you should be aware of is that currently approle assignment to groups only supports single level (i.e. nested groups are not supported).

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT Thanks for that clarification Dan. I've removed the recursive enumeration from the Gist.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT, Do application roles support nested group now ?

Comment: Is this still the best way to do this?

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT Is there any improvement in this area?