# Azure Ad/Microsoft Graph get all users with specific approle

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application that uses Azure Ad Groups to manage authorization of certain actions.
In certain places in the app we want to show the users that are authorized to perform a certain action. (for example approving the publishing of an article)

We use the MS Graph api to retrieve all users in a certain Azure Ad Group.

Now we want to use approles in a serviceprincipal/appregistration, where multiple groups can be added to a specific approle.

Now I want to retrieve a list of users that has a specific approle assigned, either directly or through a ad group added to the approle.

Is there some api to retrieve the users in this way?

Comment: is this what you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Now that is the reverse of what I need. this retrieves de approles of a specific user.
I need the users of a specific app role

Comment: then its this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003887/how-to-get-all-users-that-belong-in-an-approle-using-azure-active-directory-grap

Comment: this seems hopefull let me do a deep dive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of graph, what I believe you are looking for is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

This is the graph endpoint that gets all app role assignments for a given application

Comment: Just for information the id needed is the enterprise application object id.

Comment: Which can only be got via a `list` request requiring the `ServicePrincipalEndpoint.Read.All` permission.